# Why won't the intro start without using a timeout?

Tags: javascript, meteor, intro.js

I am in the process of installing an outside JS plugin called intro.js https://github.com/usablica/intro.js3. According to the install instructions, the only files needed are `intro.js` and `introjs.css` and then a `introJs().start();` call can be made.

Here is my environment setup :
  1. The official jQuery meteor package is installed https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/jquery
  2. `intro.js` file is inside a `client/lib/js` directory.
  3. `introjs.css` file is inside a `client/lib/stylesheets/` directory
  4. since the js will span multiple pages my call is in `body.onRendered` like so :

```
Template.body.onRendered(function () {
    introJs().start();
});
```

Which does not work, but using a `timeOut` solves the issue :

```
Template.body.onRendered(function () {
    setTimeout(function() { introJs().start(); }, 5000);
});
```

Why does using a timeout solve the issue?
Is it possible to not use one? Is so, how?

Comment: It is running wiith a 5 second timer!? May it be, something (asynchronous) is not loaded or initialized at the first run?

Comment: do you have subtemplates in `body` template?